# Can I use instant cash ISA for shares in UK?

Tags: stocks, investing, united-kingdom

Can I use instant cash ISA for buying shares in UK ?

https://www.barclays.co.uk/savings/isas/instant-cash-isa/

What advantages I will get by getting a shares ISA in UK ? one side effect is paying £4 per month.

Answer (score 1):

No. A product described as an *Instant Cash ISA* would have no provision for holding stocks/shares.

But you are able to transfer the cash within an Instant Cash ISA to an account that does permit holding stocks/shares. If you do so, make sure you get the new account provider to do an **ISA Transfer**. Do not withdraw the cash from the ISA yourself, otherwise that money loses its tax protection.

The advantage of a shares ISA is the ability to hold shares that are protected from tax. In particular there is no income tax or capital gains tax to pay regardless of the size of income or capital gains.

Over a lifetime, especially with the compounding effect of investments in shares, that could save you a lot of tax.

Stock markets **can go down as well as up**. Look elsewhere for on advice about cash safety nets, and how to invest (especially diversification and appreciating risks).

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to use the money in a cash ISA to buy a shares ISA.  If you want to maintain the ISA status, you need to follow the procedure set out by the company that you're sending the money to.  You have a limited amount (currently £20K) that you can put into an ISA per year, but transfers are not counted against that limit.

---

The main advantage that there is a possibility that you might make some money.

The interest rates paid on cash ISAs are below the rate of inflation at the moment.  So even paying no tax on the interest, your savings still lose value every year.

A shares ISA may make money, if what it's invested in goes up.  But shares can go down as well as up.  Nothing is guaranteed.